# please tell me when multiple varibles are returned which one gets stored?

Tags: c

I came across this code and want to know what this line [X] will it return:

```
int add_multiply(int a, int b)
{
  int p, q;
  p = a + b;
  q = a * b;
  return (p, q); //X
}
void main()
{
  int b, a = add_multiply(1, 2);
  b = add_multiply(3, 4);
  printf("%d%d", a, b);
}
```

Comment: Always the last one. Also, don't use void main(). thats ugly.

Comment: @Magisch Nonsense, there is nothing wrong with `void main` in a generic C context, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518).

Comment: I would be amazed if there was no dup for this:(

Answer (score 7):

You can't return more than one variable at once from a function in C. The statement

```
return(p, q); // or return p, q;
```

returns `q` only. The `,` in `p, q` is a [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). `p` will be evaluated and it's value will be discarded, then `q` will be evaluated and then its value will be returned.

Comment: You could add that's because `return` IS NOT A FUNCTION and he would get the same result with `return p, q;`.

Comment: Why is `return(p, q)` equal to `return p, q`? I mean, `int a; a = (5, 6);` and `int a; a = 5, 6;` are different...

Comment: @CoolGuy; In `a = 5, 6;`, expression will be evaluated as `(a = 5),  6;` while in `return p, q` it will be `return (p, q)`.

Comment: @haccks So, there is no way to return `p` using the comma operator in the `return` statement?

Comment: @CoolGuy; Yes, there is: `return q, p;` :)